# Which JavaScript code implements shiny's numericInput widget?

Tags: javascript, jquery, r, shiny

A call to [`numericInput()`](http://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/numericInput.html), like this:

```
numericInput("obs", "Observations:", 10, min = 1, max = 100)
```

constructs HTML code like this:

```
<div class="form-group shiny-input-container">
  <label for="obs">Observations:</label>
  <input id="obs" type="number" class="form-control" value="10" min="1" max="100"/>
</div>
```

Then, presumably, in the browser, JavaScript code provided by one of the scripts included in the HTML doc's header finds that `<input>` element and renders it with the interactive widget displayed below:

[image]

I'm having a hard time, though, figuring out where the code that finds that `<input>` element and then triggers production of the corresponding widget is stored. Is it in Shiny's own JavaScript, or in that borrowed from by Bootstrap or jQuery UI or one of the other [plugins that ship with **shiny**](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/tree/master/inst/www/shared)?

### My question(s):

Where is the JavaScript code that provides the widget pictured above and associates it with the HTML `<input>` element? And how, from the code that's involved, might I have learned that on my own?

---

**More only possibly useful details**

[This section](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/blob/master/inst/www/shared/shiny.js#L3174) of the script `"shiny.js"` finds the `<input>` element of interest, and provides methods that can get and set the widget's value. It doesn't (as far as I can see) provide the widget itself.

```
var numberInputBinding = {};
$.extend(numberInputBinding, textInputBinding, {
  find: function(scope) {
    return $(scope).find('input[type="number"]');
  },
  getValue: function(el) {
    var numberVal = $(el).val();
    if (/^\s*$/.test(numberVal))  // Return null if all whitespace
      return null;
    else if (!isNaN(numberVal))   // If valid Javascript number string, coerce to number
      return +numberVal;
    else
      return numberVal;           // If other string like "1e6", send it unchanged
  },
  setValue: function(el, value) {
    el.value = value;

  [... snip ...]

  }
});
inputBindings.register(numberInputBinding, 'shiny.numberInput');
```

And here is a copy of the `<head>` section of the the **shiny**-generated HTML file that results in the `numericInput` widget. The scripts it references can mostly be found here

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
  <script type="application/shiny-singletons"></script>
  <script type="application/html-dependencies">json2[2014.02.04];jquery[1.11.0];shiny[0.12.2];bootstrap[3.3.1]</script>
<script src="shared/json2-min.js"></script>
<script src="shared/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="shared/shiny.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="shared/shiny.min.js"></script>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
<link href="shared/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="shared/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="shared/bootstrap/shim/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
<script src="shared/bootstrap/shim/respond.min.js"></script>
  <title>Hello Shiny!</title>
</head>
```

Comment: FWIW, the widget looks a bit like a [Spinner](https://jqueryui.com/spinner/) provided by the jQuery UI plugin, but I can't for the life of me see where/how that widget gets referenced/linked to, anywhere in the relevant **shiny** codebase.

Comment: All modern browsers support <input type="number"> nothing fancy,

Comment: @epascarello Ah, interesting, thanks. Does that mean there's no JavaScript involved? Or just that there is JavaScript, but it's part of the browsers' source code?

Comment: shown right in your script  `$(scope).find('input[type="number"]');` .. looking for regular number input

Comment: Answering my own question of @epascarello just above, [Chapter 4 of "HTML5 for Web Designers"](http://html5forwebdesigners.com/forms/) seems to indicate that JavaScript's incorporation into web browsers paved the way for "form enhancements" like `<input type="number">`.

Comment: think it's more about semantics and accessibility that prompted the addition of new input types

Comment: @charlietfl Yeah, could be. As a complete newbie, I just found that first sentence enlightening, as it confirmed my hunch that it is JavaScript in the browsers' source that implements the dynamic behavior of the number widget. Here' the bit that helped: "When JavaScript was introduced into web browsers, it was immediately seized upon for two tasks: Image rollovers and form enhancements. "

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the incorrect assumption that made this so hard for me to figure out:

> Then, presumably, in the browser, JavaScript code **provided
>   by one of the scripts included in the HTML doc's header** finds that
>    element and renders it with the interactive widget displayed
>   below:

In fact, as @epascarello points out, *modern browsers themselves* support `<input type="number">`.
(For further documentation of this fact, along with a long list of the features whose support was enabled by the incorporation of JavaScript in these modern web browsers, see [Chapter 4 of "HTML for Web Designers"](http://html5forwebdesigners.com/forms/).)